# How to decide the size of image while designing a UI for android application

Tags: android, user-interface

How do I determine the size of an image while designing a UI for an android application? I want my application to support different devices with various screen sizes and resolutions. The design work for the application is being done separately by designers.

I have two questions:

1. What input can I give to the designers for designing the application's UI?
2. When I set the background of the UI to an image of a character, it seems to be stretched in a weird way.

Any links about Android design would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Both questions have been asked before - you should first try searching in the [[image]android](/questions/tagged/android) tag.

To answer your question on multiple screen sizes, you should read the Android Developer page
[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). There's a lot of information here about how Android handles hardware differences and what you can do about it.

Although unofficial, these [Android Design Guidelines](http://www.mutualmobile.com/2011/android-design-guidelines/) were recommended to me and were able to provide a baseline for some UI design choices.

Regarding your second question, setting an image to the android:background tag will by default stretch the image to fit, even if it means distorting the aspect ratio. This can lead to your image looking stretched or compressed.

Comment: +1 for the link to the Android Design Guidelines. Looks pretty exhaustive